# Is there a way to get the CurrencyISOCode of a Opportunity Owner in a formula?

Tags: multi-currency

I want to be able to compare the owner's CurrencyISOCode with the Opportunity record's CurrencyISOCode so I can enforce a validation or update a number field depending on if they match or are different.

The problem I see is that I cannot get navigate through the formula field picker to get CurrencyISOCode.

Is there something else I should try?

Comment: You have to handle through trigger

Comment: The answer to your question probably greatly depends on how many currencies you're trying to deal with. If there's only a couple, I can see possible ways of doing this via a formula, but if there's a lot of them, the method may not work or even be viable. It would involve the User's `LocaleSidKey` and translating that into a `CurrencyISOCode` using something like CASE. You might also be able to do it with the user's `Country Code` if there's a direct correlation.

Comment: thanks crmprogdev. I ended up convincing them to use another field, I think CASE(LocalSidKey) could work if ever needed in the future..